# Filipina in transit Visa gatwick

Tags: uk, tickets, transit-visas, filipino-citizens, trinidad-and-tobago

I would like to bring my girlfriend from the Phillipines to visit me in Trinidad. The easiest route seems to be manila intransit through Qatar and connect in Gatwick airport to Port of Spain Trinidad. From.my research it seems that no visa is required to transit Doha as the luggage will be checked all the way through to Gatwick. But as she will have to reclaim and recheck luggage she will require a visitor in transit visa. She will also require a visa on arrival into my country. She is currently unemployed in phillipines. I would really like to know if anyone has had experience in getting this transit visa. It seems as if you have to apply for it online but still also visit a visa application center in the Phillipines to have your biometric information collected. It all seems overwhelming. Grateful for any advice.

Comment: What exactly is your question? The application process is here https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/direct-airside-transit-visa, basically apply online and provide the required documents and biometrics

Comment: This is very plainly _not_ a duplicate of the linked question. They already know they need a transit visa. They are asking for opinions.

Comment: Correct I am asking for opinions for people who maybe a gone through the process given the variables are play

Comment: @tariqalli **WARNING**: Traveller's link is wrong. This is the one https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa

Comment: @Crazydre want to turn into an answer?